# find the equations of the tangents at the points P and Q

Tags: calculus

The curve ${y = (x -1)(x^2 + 7)}$ meets the x-axis at P and the y-axis at Q.

Find the equations of the tangents P and Q.

I am not looking for the answer but just some hints to get me started.

I am not sure how to being.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

- $P$ is where $y=0$, so either $x-1=0$ or $x^2+7=0$.
- Similarly, $Q$ is where $x=0$, in which case $y=(0-1)(0+7) = -7$.
- The tangents will be of the form $y=mx+b$. Since the line is tangent to the curve, you must evaluate the derivative at $P$ and $Q$. Whatever you get for the derivative will be the slope $m$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Find derivatives of y at x=0 and x = 1, and y values there. For each point find

$$ \frac{y-y_1}{x-x_1} = derivative $$